# Having trouble with centering inside relative

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a website where you have fixed-attached backgrounds and content that then scrolls over it. I've been mainly successful but cannot for the life of me get this text centered. I've tried multiple things as you can see in the CSS but none of them work.

I have relatively positioned the break div where I want a background that spans the whole bootstrap page and allows the user to scroll as a nice picture break between content divs.
I want to add an h1 tag with "about me" but it will not be  centered.

```
#break {
height:400px;
background-image: url("http://img.inspiringwallpapers.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/new-   york-skyline-at-sunset-from-high-above.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
z-index: 1;
position:relative;
}


#break h1 {
display: inline-block;
margin:0 auto !important;
color: white;
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jz1zr9h/
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `text-align` to the parent and some `margin-top` to the `h1`

```css
#break {
    height:400px;
    background-image: url("http://img.inspiringwallpapers.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/new-york-skyline-at-sunset-from-high-above.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#break h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 160px auto 0 !important;
    color: white;

}
```

```html
  <div id='break'>
   <h1 class='text-center'>about me</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer by @stranger4js, text align is for text. `margin: 0 auto;` will center a block but not the content within it

Answer (score 2):

try text align

```
#break h1 {
text-align:center;
color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2jz1zr9h/1/

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! But how come it wouldn't work by doing margin: 0 auto but works this way?